# Browser capabilities redirect in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to detect certain browsers (IE6) and redirect them to a page that tells them to get a better browser.

Same thing for detection of Javascript being enabled, if the browser has it disabled I want to send them to a page which explains this fact.

Is there an elegant or preferred way to do this in mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you  should first Detect Browser Types by `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser` and then you can send users to a page which tells them to get a better browser . 
and see for more information [How to: Detect Browser Types and Browser Capabilities in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is a clean and great way of doing it.

http://ie6update.com/

Comment: I cannot open this link, what was the solution shown in that page?